# How to add dimmer to "one switch controls another switch" configuration

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

In my dining room, I currently have a switch configuration that functions as follows:

- Switch 1: when toggled, turns light on/off
- Switch 2: when toggled, turns Switch 1 on/off

Can I have 2 dimmers or 1?  If so, would I use 3-way or 1-way?  Currently, both switches have 4 wires running to them, each.

Note:  House was built in 2013.

Comment: By four wires, do you mean black, red, white, and bare, or black, red, blue, white, and bare?

Comment: Black, black, red, ground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lutron makes 3 way switches for this set up that allow dimming.  I just installed one set in my basement.  One dimmer will be the base and the other talks to it.  Here is what I have - [Lutron Dimmer Set](http://www.smarthome.com/66003WH/Lutron-MAW-603-RH-WH-Maestro-600W-Wireless-3-Way-Dimmer-Kit-White/p.aspx).  With 4 wires running everywhere you should be set to install these.

Comment: I am finding that as a STEP 0 to my dimmer installation, I need to resolve the problem of my switch configuration.  My research has led me to the conclusion that my initial 3-way switch configuration was wrong.

Comment: That is a different question then.  You asked how to add dimmers for a switch that controls another.  Just ask another question for your current issue.  We would just need to know where power is coming for the two switches.

Comment: When I initially asked the question, I didn't know that my original configuration wasn't a best practice and in most cases a mistake.